# why am i getting an error using the sep function?

Tags: python

```
print(str(("Resource:",name,("Average weekly hours: "),Avg,(sep="\t"))))
```

This is my line of code, and I am getting an error sign following the `=` after `sep`. Please let me know what is wrong with this.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Max, changing the question such that it invalidates the answers is considered a bad thing since it makes the posts effectively useless for future searchers. There's no arbitrary limit on the number of questions you can ask so, if you have a different question, just ask a *new* question. I have rolled back the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The separator is an argument to `print`, which means it should occur immediately before the closing bracket. In fact, it appears you have gone rather over the top with your parentheses, to the point where it looks like you may have once been a LISP developer :-)

In other words, something like this should suffice:

```
print("Resource:", name, "Average weekly hours:", Avg, sep="\t")
```

This will output something like (the `v` markers represent tab stops):

```
       v       v       v       v       v       v
Resource:      Pax     Average weekly hours:   92
```

Comment: how I can I only make a tab stop between the two print statements, so its like "Resource: Pax"